# Push to private bitbucket repo from pipelines

Tags: git, bitbucket, push, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to commit and push to a bitbucket repo from bitbucket pipelines. However, it's a private repo so what is the easiest way to gain access to it?

This is what my script looks like:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - VERSION=$(<version.txt)
          - echo $VERSION 0.1 | awk '{print $1 + $2}' > version.txt
          - echo $(<version.txt)
          - git config --global push.default simple
          - git remote set-url origin https://myname@bitbucket.org/company/repo.git
          - git config user.name "myname"
          - git config user.email "myname@company.com"
          - git add version.txt
          - git commit -m "[skip CI]"
          - git push
          - echo "New version = $VERSION"
```

It gets stuck at the push command and returns:

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://myname@bitbucket.org': No such device or address
```

How do I set my password for it or is there a way to do it without password? For it to somehow realise that it's already within the repo itself. I read around about SSH keys but am not very familiar with the concept and how to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a secure environment variable named something like `BB_AUTH_STRING`, and give it a value of `username:password`. (It's safest to do this with an app password, since those will only work with the scope you give them.) That will also change your remote URL to `https://${BB_AUTH_STRING}@bitbucket.org/owner/repo.git`.

Comment: As of 2023 this works for me: `https://$BB_AUTH_STRING@bitbucket.org/$BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME`